# What information comes with an SMS?

Tags: android, iphone, windows-phone, sms

This seems like a topic that would be widely covered in the mobile digital age, but I haven't found much of anything.

What information comes with an SMS? Obviously the message text itself, and the number from which it was sent. Is there anything else included - GPS (long/lat) data perhaps? Device type? Carrier info? Does it vary by device and carrier?

I'm coming at this from the perspective of a web developer, where I can see calls to and responses from the server, which often include rich header data. I'm just curious what all could theoretically be similarly gleamed from an SMS.

---

This question was originally about SMS *and* MMS, but the two appear to be significantly different in operation

Comment: You may be interested to know that the two technologies are very far apart in terms of how they're implemented and how they structure messages. Essentially SMS is a by product of the way GSM networks manage themselves, in that there are spare slots for control information among the various frequency/time divisions of the cell tower radio spectrum. In contrast an MMS is a block of SMIL data transmitted over a tcp based network connection, like the mobile data connection that every smartphone cannot be smart without :). It does thus make a mockery of historical network operator charges

Comment: .. for these but the operators had to recover the billions they spent on licensing the radio spectrum somehow.. it's partly a shame that the public was mugged 10p per message for something that was always going to be there as a free side effect of how the network had to work it was used for SMS or not, but equally something had to fund the network! I don't have decent specs on what else is included in an SMS, hence didn't post an answer but the info will be out there!